# C++ equivalent of matlab regress() function

Tags: c++, matlab, math

I'm looking for C++ equivalent of `regress()` function in Matlab. It's a multi-linear regression using least square algorithm.

Currently I'm looking at the [Armadillo library](http://arma.sourceforge.net). I'm not quite sure whether it supports this algorithm or not.

Comment: This may interest you: http://www.math.ltu.se/courses/c0002m/least_squares.pdf

Comment: Hey guys! This seem to be a nontrivial question and can be reasonably answered.

Comment: Also have a look at http://www.alglib.net/ I have used the curve fitting (which is essentially regression) in C# and it is much faster and sometimes more accurate than it's matlab equivalents.

Comment: Thanks, the alglib works great and easy to use!

Answer (score 1):

Try one of the [orthogonal decomposition methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_%28mathematics%29#Orthogonal_decomposition_methods), they are supported by Armadillo.

(I don't know Matlab or what it's `regress()` function does.)